# How do I use a groupBy() with join in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a little challenge here, I want to get orders from my orders table grouping by created_at field and aggregating the amount for each date. The amount is from another table (products) called price. Order table has a product_id as foreign key. I then did this

```
        $ord = DB::table('orders')
            ->join('products', 'orders.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('DATE(orders.created_at) as created_at'),
                'products.price',
                //DB::raw('sum(products.price) as amount')
            )->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
        $ord->groupBy('created_at');
        return $ord;
```

The issue here is that when I uncomment the //DB::raw('sum(products.price) as amount'), it throws me an error  **Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column**. Without it, I have a result like this

`[{"created_at":"2020-05-26","price":"950"},{"created_at":"2020-05-18","price":"4000"},{"created_at":"2020-05-18","price":"4000"},{"created_at":"2020-05-12","price":"320"}]`

But from here, two records on the 18th with 4000 should aggregate to 8000 for that date alone, that's how I want it. Any useful help on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: try `$ord->groupBy('orders.created_at');`, when you join tables, you have to define table name in front of column name.

Comment: @NazemMahmud tried that too, same error

Comment: did you try using `groupBy()` before `get()` ? when you use `get()` or  `first()`, that means the query has ended there. try using `groupBy()` before `get()` like  `$ord = DB::table('orders')->join('products', 'orders.product_id', '=', 'products.id')->select(DB::raw('DATE(orders.created_at) as created_at'), 'products.price',
                //DB::raw('sum(products.price) as amount')
            )->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('created_at')->get();`

Comment: no, its different for groupBy, data must be obtained first

Comment: one more thing, you used groupBy() for one table and aggregate for another different table. look at your error, you can use groupBy from a different table, but you also have to use groupBy() at least on one column from the same table where aggregate method is used